# JScrollPane How do I get caret to set later

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, caret

I have an App that needs to store the current caret position, then recreate data on the scrollpane, and then put user back to the point he was looking at.

```
int scrollIndex = 0;
if(scrollPane != null) {
    scrollIndex = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();
}

scrollPane = new JScrollPane(newpanel);

scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scrollIndex);
```

This does not set the caret at the previous scroll - but at some other value I do not understand.

I also looked for getCaret but this does not seem to exist.

EDIT 1

This almost works:

```
int scrollIndex = 0;
JViewport vp = null;
if(scrollPane != null) {
    //scrollIndex = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();
    vp = scrollPane.getViewport();
}

scrollPane = new JScrollPane(newpanel);

//scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scrollIndex);
scrollPane.setViewport(vp);
```

The "view" remains constant at the scrollPoint I am looking at. BUT the scrollbar get sets back to 0 - even though view is fine. If I try to setValue as before - I get wrong view again.

When I do scrollPane.setViewport(vp); I there something else I need to do so scrollbars stay in same place?

Comment: `JScrollPane How to I get caret to set later` != moving with `JViewport`, but moving with `get/setCaret(Possition)` or ???

Comment: @mKorbel Sorry, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Caret is about Cursor possition in JTextComponents

Comment: Oh I see. Are you saying it is not relevant here? If so what do you suggest I use to put scrollBar knob back to the same position?

Comment: whats reason for..., because there isn't clear me from your code, nor from description, how is this logics proceed, otherwise to get JScrollBar possition from JScrollPane as is demonstrated in code posted here by @alex2410

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods `scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue()` and `scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scrollIndex);` work fine, try that with single `JScrollPane`.

I think your problem in creation of new instance of `JScrollPane`.

Instead of that `scrollPane = new JScrollPane(newpanel);` use

`scrollPane.getViewport().setView(newpanel);` that help you to change component at viewport for scrolling, without new instance.

Watch next example of code:

```
public class Example extends JFrame {

    private JScrollPane pane;
    private int value;

    public Example() {
        final JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);

        final JTextArea jTextArea2 = new JTextArea(10, 10);
        jTextArea2.setText("1\n21\n2\n\n\n\n\n121221\ne\n\nee\ne\n");
        pane = new JScrollPane(jTextArea);
        JButton save = new JButton("save");
        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                value = pane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();
            }
        });

        JButton load = new JButton("load");
        load.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                pane.getViewport().setView(jTextArea2);
                pane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(value);
            }
        });

        getContentPane().add(save,BorderLayout.WEST);
        getContentPane().add(pane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(load,BorderLayout.EAST);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new Example().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this first with an error using setViewPort instead of just setView. Now I have fixed and it works perfectly. Many thanks